# Writing a cron expression to execute every 15 minutes

Tags: session, cron

I am trying to setup a cron job to run the garbage collector every 15 minutes on my session directory to clean up sessions that are beyond the expiration limit I set in php.ini, in one of my subdirectory locations. I have never used cron jobs before so I was wondering if someone could help me.

What I have so far is:

```
15 * * * * /home/yadda/something/etc
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following is an expression that will execute every 15 minutes:

```
0 0/15 * 1/1 * ? *
```

So your expression would be:

```
0 0/15 * 1/1 * ? * /home/yadda/something/etc
```

You may be interested in the [cronmaker](http://cronmaker.com/) website.

Comment: is this quartz cron expression ?

Comment: throws IllegalArgumentExpression
Cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 7 in "0 0/15 * 1/1 * ? *")

Comment: @SemyonTikhonenko Simple - you passed in an extra parameter to your function. What are you calling? You should consider creating a separate question where you post your code and ask why it doesn't work. (I'd be glad to help you answer it!)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using anacron (ubuntu default), then the notation is simply */15 as in

`*/15 * * * * /home/yadda/something/etc`

Answer (score 1):

Visit [Cron Maker website](http://www.cronmaker.com/) if you are using `Quartz` `opensource` scheduler.

For every 15 Minute:

```
0 0/15 * 1/1 * ? *
```

For Every Day:

```
0 0 12 1/1 * ? *
```

Comment: Link only answers should be posted as comment.